# Year value is not showing in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to show the value of year in the view that is HTML, but year values are not showing at all. Although, My other value is showing while the condition is not acivated (like credit card), but when I activate it, year values is not showing, while values are coming from the controller and is shown in the console.

Here is the view code :-

```
<div class="col-xs-2 innerN" style="width: 14%;">   
                <select ng-disabled="page.creditcard.isDisabled" class="form-control innerN" placeholder="YYYY" name="ccExpYear" ng-model="page.expyear" required style="border-left:none">
                    <option value="XX" selected ng-if="page.creditcard.isDisabled">XX</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="year in page.yearList" value="{{year}}" ng-if="!page.creditcard.isDisabled">{{year}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

And Here is the controller code :-

```
$scope.page.monthList = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", ];
$scope.page.yearList = [];
var d = new Date();
var year = d.getFullYear();
//$scope.page.yearList.push(year);
$scope.page.expyear = year;
console.log("Pawan2", $scope.page.expyear);
for (var i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
    {
        $scope.page.yearList.push(year + i);
    };
}
$scope.years = $scope.page.yearList;
console.log("YearListPawan", $scope.page.yearList);
$scope.page.expmonth = "01";
$scope.monthList = "01";
// watcher
$scope.$watchGroup(['page.expmonth', 'page.expyear'], function(newValues, oldValues, scope) {
    //MM-YYYY
    if (typeof newValues[1] == "undefined" || typeof newValues[0] == "undefined") scope.authorize.creditCard
        .expirationDate = null;
    else $scope.authorize.creditCard.expirationDate = newValues[1] + "-" + newValues[0];
    console.log("Pawan", $scope.authorize.creditCard.expirationDate)
}, true);
```

I hope, I'm clear anough to get the answer for this. 
PS : THnx in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **ng-value** instead of value:-

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.page = {};
  $scope.page.monthList = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", ];
  $scope.page.yearList = [];
  var d = new Date();
  var year = d.getFullYear();
  //$scope.page.yearList.push(year);
  $scope.page.expyear = year;
  console.log("Pawan2", $scope.page.expyear);
  for (var i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
    {
      $scope.page.yearList.push(year + i);
    };
  }
  $scope.years = $scope.page.yearList;
  
  $scope.authorize = {creditCard: {expirationDate: 'date'}};
  
  console.log("YearListPawan", $scope.page.yearList);
  $scope.page.expmonth = "01";
  $scope.monthList = "01";
  // watcher
  $scope.$watchGroup(['page.expmonth', 'page.expyear'], function(newValues, oldValues, scope) {
    //MM-YYYY
    if (typeof newValues[1] == "undefined" || typeof newValues[0] == "undefined")
      $scope.authorize.creditCard.expirationDate = null;
    else
      $scope.authorize.creditCard.expirationDate = newValues[1] + "-" + newValues[0];
    console.log("Pawan", $scope.authorize.creditCard.expirationDate)
  }, true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="col-xs-2 innerN" style="width: 14%;">
    <select ng-disabled="page.creditcard.isDisabled" class="form-control innerN" placeholder="YYYY" name="ccExpYear" ng-model="page.expyear" required style="border-left:none">
      <option value="XX" selected ng-if="page.creditcard.isDisabled">XX</option>
      <option ng-repeat="year in page.yearList" ng-value="year" ng-if="!page.creditcard.isDisabled">{{year}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav Srivastava for the reply, I was missing the ng tag. Its working fine now.

Comment: @pawantiwari glad i could help.

Comment: @ GauravSrivatsava I have to use only value instead of ng-value, however, I was missing the function  of adding the years in the list that model that was assigned there. However, in the both ways, it is working out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I have applied to the scenario  -

And here is the controller code with few changes : -

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.page = {};
$scope.page.monthList = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", ];
$scope.page.yearList = [];
var d = new Date();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var addYears = function () {
    var d = new Date();
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    $scope.page.yearList = [];
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        $scope.page.yearList.push(year.toString());
        year++;
    }
}
addYears();
$scope.years = $scope.page.yearList;
$scope.page.expyear = d.getFullYear();
$scope.page.expmonth = "01";
$scope.monthList = "01";
// watcher
$scope.$watchGroup(['page.expmonth', 'page.expyear'], function(newValues, oldValues, scope) {
    //MM-YYYY
    if(typeof newValues[1] == "undefined" || typeof newValues[0] == "undefined")
        scope.authorize.creditCard.expirationDate = null;
    else
        $scope.authorize.creditCard.expirationDate = newValues[1] + "-" + newValues[0];
    console.log("Pawan", $scope.authorize.creditCard.expirationDate)
}, true);
```

Here is the view code :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><scriptsrc="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="col-xs-2 innerN" style="width: 14%;">   
                <select ng-disabled="page.creditcard.isDisabled" class="form-control innerN" placeholder="YYYY" name="ccExpYear" ng-model="page.expyear" required style="border-left:none">
                    <option value="XX" selected ng-if="page.creditcard.isDisabled">XX</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="year in page.yearList" value="{{year}}" ng-if="!page.creditcard.isDisabled">{{year}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Hope, this will help to others.

Comment: This is NOT the solution. @Gaurav Srivastava has a better solution and the code is clean. Ur "solution" has redundant code like `var year = d.getFullYear();`. Moreover, u convert an array of numbers into an array of strings and then when the `select` tag tries to select `2059` as the selected year it fails cuz the it is comparing a `number` with a `string`. Finally, u didn't explain ur "changes" neither ur solution, which is a bad copy of @Gaurav Srivastava. Please, read about [How to Answer a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn how to write effective answers.